# Typescript, set default values for optional parameters in class

Tags: typescript, typescript-3.6

I have this class

```
export class dialogConfig {
    title: String;
    message?: String;
    okText?: String;
    withDecline?: false;
    width?: Number;
    height?: Number;
}
```

and I have this function

```
  openDialog(config:dialogConfig){
        ...
    });
```

I wanna call the function like this

```
  openDialog({
    title: 'viola'
  }
```

The rest of the parameters that are not specified, I wanna set default values. How can I achieve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript - set default value for class members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49434944/typescript-set-default-value-for-class-members)

Answer (score 13):

Things that should probably change about this question:

- `dialogConfig` should be `DialogConfig`, as it is conventional in TypeScript for named object types to start with an uppercase letter.  Initial-lowercase identifiers usually signify variable names or possibly primitive types.
- I suspect you should be using an `interface` instead of a `class`.  The value `{title: "viola"}` is not actually an instance of any such class at runtime.  You can [use a `class` *as* an `interface`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#using-a-class-as-an-interface), which is why `openDialog({title: "viola"})` is not an error, but it's more straightforward to use an `interface` directly.  Unless you are writing `new DialogConfig()` or `instanceof DialogConfig` you don't need `class`.  And if you *are* writing those things you should be very careful with non-instance literals like `{title: "viola"}`.
- `Number` should be `number` and `String` should be `string`.  [It's almost always a mistake to use the uppercase versions of primitive data types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#general-types).
- `false` should probably be `boolean`, unless you're saying that `withDecline` should, when specified, always be `false`.  That's possible, but I'm confused about how that would work with the intended use case of specifying default values when left out. If you ever want `withDecline` to be `true`, then you want `boolean`.

That gives us this:

```
interface DialogConfig {
    title: string;
    message?: string;
    okText?: string;
    withDecline?: boolean;
    width?: number;
    height?: number;
}
```

---

That being said, here's how I'd assign default values:

```
const defaultValues = {
    message: "",
    okText: "",
    withDecline: false,
    width: 0,
    height: 0
}

function openDialog(config: DialogConfig) {
    const filledInConfig: Required<DialogConfig> = { ...defaultValues, ...config };    
    console.log(JSON.stringify(filledInConfig));
};
```

Here I'm using an object called `defaultValues`, and using [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) to create a new value with all the properties from `defaultValues` which is then overwritten with all the properties of `config`.  Assuming that `config` doesn't have any explicitly included `undefined` properties, this will result in a `filledInConfig` value of type `Required<DialogConfig>`, the same as `DialogConfig` but [with all the properties required instead of having some of them as optional](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredt).

If you don't want to use object spread there's also `Object.assign()`:

```
const filledInConfig: Required<DialogConfig> = Object.assign({}, defaultValues, config);
```

Either way will result in the desired result:

```
openDialog({
    title: 'viola'
}); 
// {"message":"","okText":"","withDecline":false,"width":0,"height":0,"title":"viola"}
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCLDgGwPYHMDC2IMwuyA3gFDI3JjBiYQBcyAzmFKLgNzW0BbCGzZxcEAPysOXEL341sAawAqEAB5gp7Ttz61kAdwYALVBASZQk1gCNs2JnBD7axgCZgT2kAFcBttCuNCYQpCZarH4BQZQAvpSUCEQcyO4Q8L6YYABqWL7CyAC8FArIQiJiLMgARDUANGXKapqsdY0Gxl7mltas8JhsEB1uwJ4mrAAMIyFhuBFT8ciJML4gCPREyNgADhAg6Fh4ABTJxKSshzgERCS4AJSlBmepJJhM7gCSIITnuKwAJQgAEdfMAoBB3AAeK54X53AB8xQoyAAdOj0plsnlMAU2PU0eizndkHFgsgXo4IKjrscAFIAZQA8gA5VEybjAGAAT2Obw+33hpHu93JLzAyH5kMFt1IACZASCwRDobCbn8kSUmbYAFYWMCouAiUggY7kOIEzFwLK5fLCAnE4V8eLO3b7NVmsr0RjVADkADdgI44L74qLlgB6CMUGoVUTiGrMdo1ZoaMCJ5NdMwWKwgCCJgZDeo1DxeRPTGqhcLp5gV71MDOB4M1BJAA)

Answer (score 4):

The less manual object assignment you can do, the better (in my opinion). Let the language built-in features handle this for you.

You can use this function signature for `openDialog` to achieve what you're looking for:

```js
// note that I have changed this to `interface` here
interface dialogConfig {
    title: String;
    message?: String;
    okText?: String;
    withDecline?: false;
    width?: Number;
    height?: Number;
}

// set your default values for any parameters here, like you see with
// message = 'default'
function openDialog ({ title, message = 'default' }: dialogConfig) {
  console.log(title);
  console.log(message);
}

openDialog({ title: 'Foobar' });
// will output:
// > Foobar
// > default
```

Comment: For this to work, ALL non-required parameters must appear in the signature.  Otherwise, they cannot be accessed: `function openDialog ({ title, message = 'default', okText, withDecline, width, height }: DialogConfig)`

Answer (score 0):

In my TS file:

```
interface IDialogConfig {
  title: string;
  message?: string;
  okText?: string;
  withDecline?: boolean;
  width?: number;
  height?: number;
}
```

But then I create a const and assign some default values in the same file:

```
export const DialogConfig: IDialogConfig = {
  title: 'My Title',
  message: 'My message",
  okText: "some text",
  withDecline: false,
  width: 24,
  height: 50
}
```

Then in some other file where I need to use the DialogConfig variable

```
import { DialogConfig } from './whereever'

console.log(DialogConfig);
```

but if I need to change a value for some other purpose:

```
const newDialogConfig = {...DialogConfig};
newDialogConfig.message = "My new message";

console.log(newDialogConfig)
```

This seems to work pretty well for me.